# Remove trailing whitespaces using sed gives wrong result

Tags: bash, sed

```
       echo "This is a test         " | sed  -e 's/[ \t]*$//'
       Gives below output-
       This is a tes
```

Actually Output should be as below-

This is a test

But at the end t is missing, can someone please figure out the same.

After some analysis i found that, if the last letter is other than t, then it is giving correct result.

Only if last letter is t, then is is getting skipped/replaced with null.

Comment: See: [site:stackoverflow.com sed remove trailing tabs spaces](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+sed+remove+trailing+tabs+spaces)

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: So you have a problem with the letter `t` in your input and your sed script contains `\t` - hmm, what **could** the issue be....?

Answer (score 1):

Use character class `[:blank:]` instead:

```
sed  -e 's/[[:blank:]]*$//'
```